# Where did Class Finder Go in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.3

Android Studio 3.3 have removed Command + O in Mac which opens up a dialog like this to find a class. I rely heavily on this command/shortcut to easily find/navigate to another class in the project.

Has anyone figured out a workaround on how to bring this back. Find in Path Shift + Option + F is not adequate. I need to be able to bring up a list of classes and select the best match for what I am looking for.

[image: Class Finder in Android Studio]

Comment: Double-shift works

Comment: That's very close, thanks